# .htaccess serve index from subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an API in PHP that I want to serve with apache using `.htaccess` files. The server is configured to host a specific directory as `https://www.example.com/~user/`.

```
/web/
├── index.html
└── api/
    ├── .htaccess
    ├── public/
    │   └── index.php
    └── src/
```

What I would like to achieve is that `https://www.example.com/~user/api/` serves the `index.php` file that is in the `public/` subdirectory while redirecting its base: `https://www.example.com/~user/api/v1/` would then be matched as `v1/` inside `index.php`.

Originally my setup featured a `.htaccess` file inside the `public/` directory but this would create an url like `https://www.example.com/~user/api/public/v1/` which is undesirable.

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~user/api/public/

# If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist,
# or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then proceed to the rewrite rule below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in your `api` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/api/
RewriteRule !^public/index\.php$ public/index.php [L]
```

In your PHP, you can get the URL that was visited from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which will contain the original URL.

If you don't want to rewrite existing files and directories, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^public/index\.php$ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me: The first block properly serves me the .php file when visiting `api/` but the URI path is `/~user/api/` which I expect to be `/`. The second block just returns a directory listing.

Comment: What do you mean, the URI path is `/~user/api/`? In your question you said you want to visit `https://www.example.com/~user/api/` and have it serve from `public`. Do you mean you actually want to visit `https://www.example.com/` and have it serve `/~user/api/public/`? Or that the URI path in PHP includes `/~user/api/`. If it's the URI path in PHP then yes, that's the full original path, just remove that part from it with a regex in your PHP using `preg_replace`.

Comment: The second one doesn't process existing directories, so yes it would do that. You can remove the directory check `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` so it only checks for files, but it's only if you want to avoid rewriting existing URIs.

Comment: If I do RewriteBase as in my example `$request->getUri()->getPath()` resolves to `/`. Now with the changes it resolves to `/~user/api/`. And ty - I've overlooked the directory property.

Comment: So just strip the part out of the path variable that you don't want, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is my solution right now. But I would like to make it domain agnost by resolving it in `.htaccess`. I plan to deploy on a root domain at a later stage without hosting on `/~user/`